# TestOutput folder missing in jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

[TestOutput folder missing in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKKe9.png)

I am able to get test output folder while running in my local IDE but its not getting generated in jenkins workspace as attached screenshot

How to generate test output folder which contains **testng** report.xml and other vital files

Comment: how you are running? means command used in jenkins. As u said working fine in local, u tried with same command in local too?

Comment: How you are executing your test ? Are you using maven?  if so then then the folder path should be /target/surefire-reports/